# Sql Server 2012 Change Data Capture weird behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

In my Sql Server 2012 I have the following table in a database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HumanResource](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsHired] [bit] NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Score] [bigint] NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_HumanResource] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

when I update the Address field (nvarchar, **not null**), it is captured as below

NULL       3      2   mahmood True    **here**    111 2014-09-01 14:42:28.913
   NULL       4      2   mahmood True    **there**   111 2014-09-01 14:42:28.913

but when I update the Score field (nvarchar, **null**), this is captured

NULL       3      2   mahmood True    ***NULL***  111 2014-09-01 14:42:28.913
   NULL       4      2   Mahmood True    **there**   111 2014-09-01 14:42:28.913

---

**Edit (the update and select queries) :

```
update HumanResource set Address = 'blah blah blah' where id = 2
update HumanResource set Score = Score + 1 where id = 2

SELECT        TOP (10000) __$start_lsn, __$end_lsn, __$seqval, __$operation,  
__$update_mask, ID, Name, IsHired, Address, Score, LastUpdate
FROM            cdc.dbo_HumanResource_CT
```

### [image]

Considering that sql server Update is a chained *Delete and Insert*, the first row is the delete row capture and the second one is the insert row capture.

But I don't understand why the address is tracked as NULL when I update other fields, I would appreciate any information on this issue.

Comment: (1) can you show the `UPDATE` statements instead of describing them? (2) how are you determining "first" and "second"? What query are you using to pull the CDC data? Does it have an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand please check the updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500305.aspx)

> #### Large Object Data Types
>
> Columns of data type **image**, **text**, and **ntext** are always assigned a **NULL** value when __$operation = 1 or __$operation = 3. Columns of data type **varbinary(max)**, **varchar(max)**, or **nvarchar(max)** are assigned a **NULL** value when __$operation = 3 unless the column changed during the update. When __$operation = 1, these columns are assigned their value at the time of the delete. Computed columns that are included in a capture instance always have a value of **NULL**.
>
> By default, the maximum size that can be added to a captured column in a single INSERT, UPDATE, WRITETEXT, or UPDATETEXT statement is 65,536 bytes or 64 KB. To increase this size to support larger LOB data, use the [Configure the max text repl size Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-text-repl-size-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) to specify a larger maximum size. For more information, see [Configure the max text repl size Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-text-repl-size-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16).

You are using a `nvarchar(max)`. I've got the same problem.
I fix it by changing my `varchar(max)` with `varchar(255)`. For an address `255` should be enough.

Hope this help